# How to wait for a Transaction ends in JDO?

Tags: java, jdo, kodo

I encounter a issue that in the worst case only happens. Ex. I have a Job that runs every minute

```
    UpdateJobForAnObjectA:
    PersistenceManager pm = Context.getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    update a collection of an ObjectA
    tx.comit();
    pm.close();
```

Now I have a deadlock(Pessimist Strategy) or an opstimic lock violation(Optimistic Violation) if in another segment I update an objectA. I set to nonTransactionalRead and nonTransacionalWriete and still I'm having the error of deadlock or opstimic lock violation. But there is a way that see if I can wait for a transaction ends? Using JDO and KODO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a [Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/transaction/Synchronization.html) object on the [Transaction](http://www.datanucleus.org/javadocs/javax.jdo/3.2/javax/jdo/Transaction.html#setSynchronization-javax.transaction.Synchronization-), and use its methods to be notified when a txn commits/rolls back.